# C: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type error on BST print out

Tags: c, printf, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to print out words stored in a BST of linked lists. When I try to print the word it gives me the "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type" error.

My print function is in my header file for the BST struct. In my main function I can print out like this without an issue, but it doesn't seem to want to print in this function.

```
//linked list struct
struct ll_node
{
    char * word;
    struct ll_node * next;  
};



//BST struct
struct bst_node
{
    int occurs;
    int diffOccurs;

    struct bst_node * left;
    struct bst_node * right;

    struct ll_node * words;
};



//printout function
void * printTree(struct bst_node * currBST)
{
    if(currBST == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }

    printf("%s\n", currBST->words->word);

    printTree(currBST->left);
    printTree(currBST->right);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`struct bst_node` and `struct ll_node` should both be defined *before* you use `currBST->words->word`.

Comment: They are both defined. The whole tree is built and then I call the print statement. I can hard code print statements into my main function but calling this function when it is in a header file won't seem to work.

edit: In my actual code the print function is after the structs, sorry if that was confusing.

Comment: It can't be **this** error message if both structures are defined before print (it doesn't matter that you build the tree before printing, the problem is the order of definition and usage in *source code*. That is, "before" means literally "closer to the beginning of source file", and not something about the order of *doing* things in your program).